# Big Query Export with more than 4 million rows not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

A question regarding google big query.  I've activated the free trial and I'm trying to export all the data (all events) from ga4_obfuscated_sample_ecommerce (google merchandise store). It's about 4 million rows.First I've saved the query result on a biq query table(select * from ...). I've created a bucket on cloud storage and exported the result of the query , as csv with GZIP compression.
Unfortunately, although there was a message that export initiated, I never got any file in the bucket.
Do you possibly know what I'm doing wrong? i'm new to big query.

Comment: Hi again, I've just noticed this error --->Operation cannot be performed in a nested schema. Field: Event_params. So I guess I have to unnest this field.

Answer (score 0):

You have nested fields in your `BigQuery` table and you can't export nested fields in a `csv` file.

You need to flatten your fields in your sql query before to export them to a `csv` file, example :

```sql
select 
   field1
   myRecord.field2
   ........
```